# Separting the development and production environment in GOLANG

Tags: go, go-iris

I am new to GO programming. I came from nodejs. It was easy to separate the dev and  prod mode in nodejs. By simply using this code.

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==="production"){
   server.listen(prod.port);
} 
else{
   server.listen(dev.port);
}
```

I basically want this convention to use in GO too. So how could I separate my dev and production code.

The reason why want this feature is

> to separate the port my server is listening in dev and prod
>   environment

If there is any technique to separate the port, It would work either.

> P.S: I am using VScode as my code editor. And `go-iris` as a go server
>   framework

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't do it this way because it leads to a ton of duplication. There really is little reason to need to switch between environments like this, so youre just writing the same code over and over. Use 1 env and thats it. Change the env to fit the env, not the code to fit the env

Comment: Especially considering the massive out of the box development tools that comes native to GO, you should really have no need for hardcoded environment duplicated code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use `os.Getenv` function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func getEnv() string{
    return os.Getenv("APP_ENV")
}
```

https://golang.org/src/os/env.go?s=2471:2501#L73

Comment: Used same function by assigning to a variable like `port:=os.Getenv("APP_ENV")` didn't worked but when used directly with `if os.Getenv("APP_ENV")=="production"{ // }` worked

Comment: can you past part of the code that is using `port`?

Comment: i didn't get u, do u mean cast or past

Comment: sorry, I meant *paste. I cannot see why `port` variable should not store a string value. If you can show me the problematic part(of your code), I may be able to improve the answer.

Comment: sorry that was `env` variable not `port`  `env:=os.Getenv("APP_ENV");                                                                            
   if env=="production"{
 
   }else{
     
   }`

Comment: `if env := os.Getenv("APP_ENV"); env != "" {
  fmt.Println(os.Getenv("APP_ENV"))
 }` works for me.

Answer (score 17):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this in Go, but all of them do not handle this in the code itself.

1. Use environment variables, eg `os.Getenv`
2. Parse config files, eg some `.yaml` file
3. Use flags, eg `package flag`

I think the most common solution is using flags but all do the same job. Usually you parse your flags in the main method.

Comment: Yes! This is ideal. And if not the main, then for sure `init()` - especially when parsing different flags in different packages

Comment: Or you can use all 3, plus hard-coded defaults, in any order of precendence if you roll it manually, or you can use something like https://github.com/spf13/viper to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your application with arguments, such as `go run main.go -mode development`, while the default mode is production. You can start your application with scripts in order to seperate different environments. For example, your bootstrap.bat file may look like this: `go run main.go -mode development`.